# How to connect Lenovo a7000 as external emulator in android studio?

Tags: android, emulation

Is there is any way to connect non nexus devices as emulator in android studio?

Comment: do you want to use real device for development??

Comment: A real device is not an emulator

Comment: search for how to use real device with android studio

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/112054/131253

Comment: You can use genymotion to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are window user, first install Lenovo Driver for Window,

If Developer Option is not enabled, Setting > About Phone > Press BuildNumber 7 times

Go to Developer Options and please enable USB Debugging.

If popup appear, please tap to allow device.

And then , you can run your Android Projects with your real device

Answer (score 0):

You can simply plug in your phone with Developer Mode enabled. When you click on Debug, it automatically shows up your phone. It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on Developer mode by tapping 5 times on the build number.
2. Go to Developer options, turn on USB debugging.
3. Plugin the device
4. A popup will appear. Click on allow device.
5. You are all done !